# Why iis return 403 error code with asp net mvc controller file stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

I have a controller whit two methods

```
public ActionResult Index1(string c, string d)
    {
        string path = "some path";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            return base.File(bytes, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path));
        }

        path = "/assets/images/no.jpg";
        return File(path, "application/jpeg", "no.jpg");
    }
public ActionResult Index2(string c, string d)
    {
        string path = "some path";
        string _nomefile = "some name";
        string _mime = "";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), _mime) { FileDownloadName = _nomefile};

        }
        path = "/assets/images/no.jpg";
        return File(path, "application/jpeg", "no.jpg");
    }
```

This are used by view like this

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Titolo))
        {
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12  immagini margin-bottom-20">
                <a class="image-hover" href="/Index1?c=@item.Immagine&d=N" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@item.Titolo - @item.Descrizione">
                    <img src="/Index1?c=@item.Immagine&d=M" alt="@item.Titolo"><br />
                    <span>@item.Descrizione</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        }
```

The problem is that IIS return an intermittent 403 forbidden with both methods  and this is totally random. On a list with 30 images 3 or 4 are not displayed.
I do not have any authentication implemented and all files are on the same machine.

Comment: Do you get 403 error with specific image files or is it random?

Comment: It is totally random. if i copy/paste the same link in a browser, it woks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was my solution.

It was necessary to set lower limits in IIS 8.5

https://serverfault.com/a/908740